# С#. Вызов метода из метода в одном классе

Tags: c#

Ну очень глупый вопрос наверное :(

Распихал логику по методам, мне удобнее когда каждая функция свое выполняет.

И приходится постоянно делать так

`myclass.doing1(new myclass().doing2(new myclass().doing3()))`

this так не работает, без создания экземпляра класса они тоже не работают. Как в шарпе это делают?

Почерпнул новой инфы, большое спасибо!

Comment: объявить 1 экземпляр myclass и просто вызвать 3 метода?

Comment: @LiptonDev  Ага, тоже вариант... Я почему-то не вижу сильной разницы между 1 экземпляром и новыми. А по части логики, у меня ошибки есть? Или такое бывает, что в одном классе несколько функций и их вызывают так, как вы сказали?

Comment: Вообще, если у вас класс используется много где и часто, но несет в себе только какие-то функции, то лучше запихать это все в static класс

Comment: Может вы говорите о цепном вызове? То есть `myclass.doing1().doing2().doing3();`. Если да, то это реализуется очень легко, путем возврата методом обратно класс (`public myclass doing1(){/// return this;}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо, чтобы функции работали без создания экземпляра, сделайте их статическими. Пример:

```
public static class Mathf {
    public static float Sqrt (float x) {...}
    public static float Sin  (float x) {...}
    public static float Cos  (float x) {...}
}
```

И вызывайте через точку после имени *класса*: `x = Mathf.Sqrt (Mathf.Cos (x));`

А если используете `using static` в начале файла, то и имя класса будет необязательным.

Теперь немного поясню про экземпляры и `this`. ООП придумали, грубо говоря, чтобы упростить работу с наборами данных при помощи наборов функций, объединили данные и функции в одно целое и назвали класс.

Когда вы создаете экземпляр класса, вы создаете набор переменных, которые в нем есть, только в ООП они называются полями. Конструктор инициализирует их согласно логике класса. Поэтому, если вам не нужно работать с полями, то можно избежать работы с ними в конструкторе, если метод будет статическим.

Внутри нестатических методов вы можете использовать слово `this`. Это ссылка на экземпляр, у которого вызвали метод. Если вы пишете `myClass.f1()` то метод `f1` может обращаться к нестатическим полям и методам экземпляра `myClass`: `this.f2()` или просто `f2()`.

Статические методы вызываются без экземпляра, поэтому там вы не сможете использовать `this`, хоть явно, хоть неявно.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.doing1( myclass.doing2( myclass.doing3() ) );
```

или

```
public class MyClass
{
  ...
  public void DoIt() {
    doing1( doing2( doing3() ) );
  }
}

MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.DoIt();
```

Comment: А как doing-и выполнятся без инициализации myclass? У меня так не получается.

Comment: @keltkelt так вот же инициализация, внизу: `MyClass myclass = new MyClass();`

Comment: @trollingchar В первом варианте ответа ее не было.